# Wordpress Rest Api How do I call the next 10 posts when scrollview ends?

Tags: android, wordpress, android-studio, wordpress-rest-api

In my Android app, Wordpress Rest api is only calling 10 posts.

When I move to the end of the screen I want to call the next 10 more posts. And when it comes to the end of it, I want to call the 10 posts next.

There will be hundreds of posts in the meantime.

How can I do it?

```
getPost(){swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Ayarlar.base_url_deneme)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();
    Connect connect = retrofit.create(Connect.class);



    Call<List<Post>> call = connect.getPost(Ayarlar.get_post_url_deneme);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

            Log.e("response",""+response.code());


            if (response.code()==200){
                List<Post> postList = response.body();
                PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(TurkUser.this,postList);
                LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(TurkUser.this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(TurkUser.this,"Hata veriler çekilemedi.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.e("onFailure", "hata veriler çekilemedi "+t+" "+call);


            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);



        }
    });
```

}